# Using AWS Cloudwatch to monitor C++ (on-premises, not cloud) program

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to create a simple C++ program that sends something like a real-time status message to AWS CloudWatch to inform that it is up and running, and the status goes offline when it's closed (real-time online/offline status). The C++ program will be installed at multiple users' computers, so there will be like a dashboard on CloudWatch. Is this even possible? I'm lost on AWS between Alarms/Logs/Metrics/Events..etc.

I also want to send some stats from each PC where the program is installed, like CPU usage for example, is it possible to make a dashboard on CloudWatch to monitor this as well? Am I free to create dashboard with whatever data I want? All the tutorials I found talk about integrating CloudWatch with other AWS services (Like Lambda and EC2) which isn't my case.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to monitor a process will be using AWS CloudWatch procstat plugin. First, create a CloudWatch configuration file with PID file location from EC2 and monitor the memory_rss parameter of the process. You can read [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Agent-procstat-process-metrics.html) more.

For `stats` you can install CloudWatch Agent on each machine and collect necessary metrics. You can read [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html) more.

Comment: This is great, thank you so much. One little thing I still wonder about, the documentation says that those two services work with Windows server or Linux servers, but what if I want to use them on Windows 10 for example or Ubuntu linux, do you think that will be possible? 
And is it possible to integrate CloudWatch agent within a program and pre-configure it?
Massive thanks.

Comment: This you will have to try since the Service is meant to integrate and work within the AWS ecosystem. For CW Agent Integration I don't think it is possible.